# SQLAlchemy 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am working with JSON SQLAlchemy column and my query statement needs the 'has_key' attribute, but apparently my 'Comparator' object doesn't have this attribute.

```
Transaction.query.filter(Transaction.fields.has_key('issuername')).all()
```

where Transaction.fields is a Column(JSON). I get error "AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Transaction.fields has an attribute 'has_key'". My SQLAlchemy is latest version 1.09. Am I building this query wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has_key` operator is specific to [JSONB](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB)

> The `JSONB` type includes all operations provided by `JSON`, including the
>   same behaviors for indexing operations. It also adds additional
>   operators specific to `JSONB`, including `JSONB.Comparator.has_key()`,
>   `JSONB.Comparator.has_all()`, `JSONB.Comparator.has_any()`,
>   `JSONB.Comparator.contains()`, and `JSONB.Comparator.contained_by()`.

For JSON column you can use `->` PostgreSQL operator (get JSON object field by key)

```
Transaction.query.filter(Transaction.fields.op('->')('issuername')!=None).all()
```